# Cant read input file-Java

Tags: java, file, stack-trace

So I am following a series of tutorials to learn how to make a game in java(i am still pretty new), and i think i followed his code exactly, but it still prints the stack trace when i run it. Here is my code...

Game.java

```
package com.game.src.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final int WIDTH = 320;
    public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;
    public static final int SCALE = 2;
    public final String TITLE = "2D Space Game";

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame(TITLE);
    private boolean running = false;
    private Thread thread;
    private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    private BufferedImage spriteSheet = null;

    private BufferedImage player;

    public void init(){
        BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
        spriteSheet = loader.loadImage("/sprite_sheet.png");

        SpriteSheet ss = new SpriteSheet(spriteSheet);
        player = ss.grabImage(1, 1, 32, 32);
    }

    public void run(){
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        final double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long now = 0;
        int updates = 0, frames = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();

        init();
        while(running){
            now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            if(delta >= 1){
                tick();
                updates++;
                delta--;
            }
            render();
            frames++;

            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
                timer += 1000;
                frame.setTitle("2-D Space Game  ||  Updates: " + updates + ", FPS: " + frames);
                frames = 0;
                updates = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    private void tick(){

    }

    private void render(){
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        if(bs == null){
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        /////////////////////////////////////

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        g.drawImage(player, 100, 100, this);

        /////////////////////////////////////
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    private synchronized void start(){
        if(running) return;
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    private synchronized void stop(){
        if(!running) return;
        try{
            thread.join();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(1);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Game game = new Game();
        game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
        game.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
        game.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));

        game.frame.add(game);
        game.frame.pack();
        game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        game.frame.setResizable(false);
        game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        game.frame.setVisible(true);
        game.start();
    }
}
```

SpriteSheet.java

```
package com.game.src.main;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class SpriteSheet {
    private BufferedImage image;

    public SpriteSheet(BufferedImage image){
        this.image = image;
    }

    public BufferedImage grabImage(int col, int row, int width, int height){
        return image.getSubimage((col * 32) - 32, (row * 32) - 32, width, height);
    }
}
```

BufferedImageLoader.java

```
package com.game.src.main;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class BufferedImageLoader {
    private BufferedImage image;

    public BufferedImage loadImage(String path){
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return image;
    }
}
```

Now here is the stacktrace that shows up:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
    at com.game.src.main.BufferedImageLoader.loadImage(BufferedImageLoader.java:13)
    at com.game.src.main.Game.init(Game.java:30)
    at com.game.src.main.Game.run(Game.java:45)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can anyone help?
BTW:
sprite_sheet.png does exist

Comment: where have you put your  sprite_sheet.png file? make sure it is on the classpath

Comment: at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388) It can't find a file named sprite_sheet.png in the path you have mentioned. (/sprite_sheet.png). Try giving the absolute path like /home/workspace/images/sprite_sheet.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. My sprite_sheet.png was in my "res" folder, and i needed to add it to the build path

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is with the way you are addressing your png, and that the location you are specifying is not in your build path, or where you expect it to be. If you provide me the `pwd`on your location I will update with actual path you should use

You either need to provide the full path

`/home/me/myprogram/sprite_sheet.png`

or use relative path

`./sprite_sheet.png`

Your program is looking for the file in the root directory `/`

Comment: It's a resource, not a file.

Comment: i dont understand your comment

Comment: You don't understand the issue. A resource is loaded by `getResourceAsStream()` and it is named relative to the CLASSPATH. It isn't in the file system, and unless the JAR file contains a directory called `/home/me/myprogram/sprite_sheet.png` your answer is 100% wrong.

Comment: He is looking to look a picture file called sprite_sheet.png, I would reread the question if I where you and delete that 2nd comment...If the jar contained that directory and file, that would not be the correct way to load the picture.

Comment: If the JAR contains the file, `getResource()` and friends are the *only* correct ways to load the picture, and an absolute or relative path in the file system such as you are recommending here will not work.

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide a full path *relative to your CLASSPATH,* or a relative path relative to the current class's package.